# Setting app-ads.txt with firebase successfully but HTTP 404 appears

Tags: android, html, firebase, web, admob

- I have just set up app-ads.txt successfully with firebase hosting, step by step . But when i go to "myProjectId.web.app/app-ads.txt" error 404 appear. Thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the file name is **"app-ads.txt"** and not **"app-ads.txt.txt"**

Usually, on Windows, if you use the `right-click -> New -> Text File` sequence to create a .txt file and named it "app-ads.txt", the resulting file will be app-ads.txt.txt (Windows will automatically add .txt extension to the entered name).

You can check the actual file name from the command line by typing `dir` inside the public folder.

Answer (score 0):

when you hit the URL index.html gets fired. You need to remove index.html.

Comment: i've removed index.html from my "public" folder, but nothing changed. sorry im new

Comment: have you hosted your site on the correct domain?

Answer (score 0):

- Are you using OneDrive?
- You should disable sync mode
- Copy the project to a partition without sync
- Recreate a new app-ads file and redeploy

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).